# Need help to solve 400 bad request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Im trying to fetch an give data to a POST-method getNumbers in the server, that has a parameter id, which simply returns the id for debugging purposes. So in the Client i do as following:

```
 documentClickHandler=(number)=> {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ id: number })
    };
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/Documents/GetNumber", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => { console.log('request failed', error); });
  }

Which only has the purpuse to give the id to the getNumber method in the server:


[HttpPost("GetNumber")]
public string GetNumber([FromBody] string id)
       return id;
} 

This gives me an error (400 bad request) and I dont know how to solve it. Any ideas? Im in desperate need of help.
```

Comment: Can you use the debugging tools in your browser to see the request being sent to the server?

Comment: @AliK the id doesnt get sent to the server

Comment: It seems you are not passing id anywhere you are just declaring it the id would be passed using something like {id:'abc'} So try that instead of id:number.

Comment: @AliK I think the problem lays in the fact that the server never recives the id from the client. When the client clicks on a table it console.logs the id, but the server never recives that id, which i dont understand

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on controller constructor to ensure the controller is hit when you start the call?

Comment: @AliK I'll try changing it from id:number to id:'number'

Answer (score 4):

Remove word "number" from your code. It is a reserved word

try this code:

```
 documentClickHandler=(documentId)=> {

   var id="123"; // try this value at first, after this use your value

    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
  
      body: {id: id}
    };
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/Documents/GetNumber", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => { console.log('request failed', error); });
  }
```

and action

```
[Route("~/api/Documents/GetNumber")]
public string GetNumber( string id)
       return id;
}
```

Comment: I tried that (difference: var id = number), but it still didnt work. Maybe number is int?

Comment: Pls just try the code  as it is in my answer and let me know

Comment: hmm, I get 415 (Unsupported Media Type) now

Comment: Now i get: request failed SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: Does it go inside of action now?  If yes,  what is Id value?

Comment: "request failed SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" is what i get. Im not able to see if it went inside of the action

Comment: Can you post a debugger break point inside of the action?

Comment: and try alert(id) inside of  javascript

Comment: the alert pops up (123), but i get this:

Comment: "request failed SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input". So I dont know wheater or not the id got sent to the action

Comment: Try to check developer tools in your browser. Select Console

Comment: I'll try more. I really dont understand the problem. Thank you so much for your help! I wont bother u more than I've aleready have

Comment: Just last thing. Try to add  [FromBody] before the action Id. I don't know how fetch is working, maybe it can help.

Comment: I had [FromBody] at first, but it didnt work. Its quite strange

Comment: FromBody works from Postman,  but it usually doesn't work with  net core and ajax, I don't know about fetch

Answer (score 1):

Pl find here a sample to call your HttpPost method through Postman:
[image]

Just pass your body:

```
body: JSON.stringify(id)
```

Comment: I've done that + added [FromBody] in the parameter at the server side, and now I get 415 Unsupported media type. I really dont get this, it shoul be quite simple.

Comment: The only thing the server does is as following:
[HttpPost("GetDocument")]
        public string GetNumber([FromBody] string id)
        {
            return id;
        }

Comment: And in the client, I did exactly what the person that commented over you did. Now I get the error 415

Comment: Pleaase try with body: JSON.stringify(id)